# How to check if datetime columns in dataframe is in 15minute intervals?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a datetime column `dt` in a dataframe `df`. I want to check to that all minute values are either `00, 15, 30, 45`. Is there an inherent dataframe method that allows me to do this?

Comment: What should be the result for "2023-03-18 22:00", "2023-03-19 22:15", "2023-03-20 22:30" and "2023-03-21 22:45"?

Comment: @Corralien It should be true since it's an 15min interval

Comment: No I don't think so, check carefully the dates 2023-03-18, 2023-03-19, 2023-03-20 and 2023-03-21.

Comment: @Corralien I'm confused. Why do the dates matter? only the minutes and seconds should matter? I only need to check that the datetime ends at exactly a 15minute interval with respect to a whole hour

Comment: *Why do the date matter?* I don't know :-) Maybe it's possible (or not). We don't know about your dataframe. Can you provide use cases (working and not working examples), please? You can also take the min and max dates, use `date_range` with a frequency of 15 minutes then compare this `DatetimeIndex` with the values of your dataframe. If the intersection of both is empty, your dataframe is right else you will have missing dates.

Answer (score 2):

There is no immediate method, but you can do:

```
is_15_interval = df['dt'].dt.second.eq(0).all() \
               & df['dt'].dt.minute.isin(np.arange(4)*15).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is unclear if you just want to know if all minutes should be 00, 15, 30, 45 but you don't say anything about dates, hours or seconds.

```
>>> df
                   dt
0 2023-03-18 22:00:00
1 2023-03-19 22:15:00
2 2023-03-20 22:30:00
3 2023-03-21 22:45:00
```

The code of @QuangHoang returns True for that but should it be? Maybe it's obvious for you but not for me :-). Pandas have a method to [infer the frequency](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.infer_freq.html). It's not perfect but it could help:

```
>>> df
                   dt
0 2023-03-18 22:00:00
1 2023-03-18 22:15:00
2 2023-03-18 22:30:00
3 2023-03-18 22:45:00
4 2023-03-18 23:00:00
5 2023-03-18 23:15:00
6 2023-03-18 23:30:00
7 2023-03-18 23:45:00

>>> pd.infer_freq(df['dt'])
'15T'
```

You can combine both answers:

```
is_15_interval = (df['dt'].dt.second.eq(0).all() & 
                  df['dt'].dt.minute.isin(np.arange(4)*15).all() & 
                  (pd.infer_freq(df['dt']) == '15T'))
```